Stratonovich multiplication
I’m currently studying a paper Brownian heat engine with active reservoirs, and I have encountered some problems regarding Stratonovich multiplication.
This is a part of the content in the article:
$$dz=-Azdt+d\Xi$$
where $z$ is a d-dimensional state (column) vector and $A$ is a
linear force matrix. The noise vector $d\Xi$
satisfies $\langle d\Xi(t)\rangle=0$
and $\langle d\Xi(t)d\Xi^T (t)\rangle=2Ddt$, where $D$ is a symmetric diffusion
matrix.
$$\Sigma=\langle zz^T\rangle_s=\Sigma^T$$
where $\langle \cdots \rangle_s$ denotes the steady-state average. Its incremental
satisfies
\begin{align*}
d\Sigma &=\langle dz\circ z^T\rangle_s+\langle z\circ dz^T\rangle_s\\
&=[-A\Sigma-\Sigma A^T+2D]dt \tag{1}
\end{align*}
with the Stratonovich multiplication $\circ$
Similarly, we find
$$\langle \mathbf{z}\circ \dot{\mathbf{z}}^T\rangle_s=-\Sigma A^T +D \tag{2}$$
My question:
I know the definition of the Stratonovich integral and its relationship with the Ito integral, but I’m not very clear about the definition of Stratonovich multiplication. This makes it difficult for me to understand the above content.
For equation (1), I can use Ito formula to get it:
\begin{align*}
d\Sigma &= \langle d(\mathbf{z}\mathbf{z}^T)  \rangle\\
&= \langle d\mathbf{z}\mathbf{z}^T\rangle_s + \langle \mathbf{z} d\mathbf{z}^T\rangle_s  + \frac{1}{2}\cdot 2\langle d\mathbf{z}d\mathbf{z}^T \rangle_s\\
&= \langle (-\mathbf{A} \mathbf{z} \, dt + d\Xi)\mathbf{z}^T\rangle_s + \langle \mathbf{z}(-\mathbf{z}^T \mathbf{A}^T \, dt + d\Xi^T)\rangle_s +\langle d\Xi d\Xi^T\rangle_s\\
&= [-A\Sigma - \Sigma A^T+2\mathbf{D}]dt
\end{align*}
But I don’t know how to derive equation (2). I want to understand the specific definition of Stratonovich multiplication so that I can derive equations (1) and (2).

The authors of that paper refer to the book [32] H. Risken, The Fokker-Planck Equation, Methods of Solution and Applications  (Springer, 1996). This makes it pretty obvious what you have to do.
